# How to write a file to a directory or folder. Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory

Ruby beginner. I figured out basics of writing files. The next thing I want to try to learn to do, is save the .txt files in a folder or directory. I know I need to be specific about the path.

```
puts "Enter name:"
name = gets.strip
filename = "#{name}.txt"
puts "Enter number:"
number = gets.strip
number_in_file = "#{number}"

File.write(filename, number_in_file)
```

I found the the directory I'm in is "/Users/realfauxreal" by using irb and Dir.pwd.
I've made a dir called "list" that is "/Users/realfauxreal/list"

Any hints on how I would rewrite the

```
File.write(filename, number_in_file)
```

Obviously it's not

```
File.write"/Users/realfauxreal/list/"(filename, number_in_file)
```

but to send it to the "Users/realfauxreal/list" ? Or is it much more complex than syntax, and I'm missing some things I need to work on still. I'm just not sure how to specify to tell it where to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of these should work:

```rb
# Simply specify the entire path when calling File.write
File.write("/Users/realfauxreal/list/#{name}.txt", number_in_file)

# Or specify your path when assigning filename variable
filename = "/Users/realfauxreal/list/#{name}.txt"
File.write(filename, number_in_file)

# Or use a separate variable for folder path and then concatenate when
# needed (when calling File.write)
filename = "#{name}.txt"
folder = "/Users/realfauxreal/list/"
File.write(folder + filename, number_in_file)

# Or just specify the full filename directly when making the call:
File.write("/Users/realfauxreal/list/#{name}.txt", number_in_file)
```

Main idea is that you want to change the way you compute/assign the first argument of the `File.write` call.